# Argument type 'Range<Int>' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence' Swift3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, range, swift3

Hi i get error after Swift3. How can i fix this error? These methods provide non-repeated random numbers.

```
 func uniqueRandoms(_ count: Int, inRange range: Range<Int>, blacklist: [Int] = []) -> [Int] {
    var r = [Int](range)
        .filter{ !blacklist.contains($0) }
        .shuffle()

    return Array(r[0..<count])
}



extension Array {
func shuffle() -> Array<Element> {
    var newArray = self

    for i in 0..<newArray.count {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(newArray.count)))
        guard i != j else { continue }
        swap(&newArray[i], &newArray[j])
    }

    return newArray
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `lowerBound`and `upperBound` property of range to create sequence for Array of `[Int]`.

```
var r = [Int](range.lowerBound..<range.upperBound)
```

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: Shame it doesn't work for generics conforming to SignedInteger. For that you need to also convert it using `toIntMax()`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `CountableRange<Int>`.